# Cross model update in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm really new to ASP.NET Core so I apologize if this is a silly question, but I've spent so many hours trying to figure this out.

I have 2 models, `Teacher` and `Student`. The relationship is one teacher to many students. This is a backend API project and Im working on a PUT method which can update fields in both models simultaneously in one request.

Here's my `Teacher` class:

```
public partial class Teacher
{
        public Teacher()
        {
            Students = new HashSet<Student>();            
        }

        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ... tons of other properties ...
}
```

Here's my `Student` class:

```
public partial class Student
{       
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }        
}
```

Here's the controller:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutTeachers(int id, TeacherViewModel model)
{            
    var result = await _service.UpdateAsync(model);          
    return Ok(result.Message);
}
```

(The code above is simplified)
- It takes in a `TeacherViewModel` which restricts the number of fields to be returned
- I used another class as a service to do the update

Here's the service class:

````
public class TeacherService
{
        private readonly Repository<Teacher> _repository;        

        public TeacherService(DatabaseContextWrapper context)
        {
            _repository = new Repository<Teacher>(context);            
        }

        public async Task<ITransactionResult> UpdateAsync(TeacherViewModel model)
        {
            var teacher = _repository.FindAsync(model.TeacherId).Result;

            teacher.TeacherId = model.TeacherId;
            teacher.Name = model.Name;           

            teacher.Students.Clear();

            foreach(var student in model.Students)
            {
                teacher.Students
                    .Add(new Student
                    {
                        Id = Student.Id,
                        TeacherId = Student.TeacherId
                        Name = Student.Name
                    });```
            }
        }
}
````

My reasoning is to add the `Student` model to the to students under the `Teacher` model but it doesn't iterate through. If I comment out the clear code, the update will work but it won't cross update. It just simply wont iterate through. I guess I'm pretty lost at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit 1 (Entity relationship configuration)

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Student>(entity =>           {                           
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Teacher)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Students)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TeacherId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Students_Teachers");
            });
```

This is my configuration

Comment: Did you try to configure relationship between models in OnModelCreating ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration

Comment: Yup, I think i did it correctly. Its on Edit 1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the reverse config to your parents entity:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>(entity =>           
            {                           
                entity.HasMany(d => d.Students)
                    .WithOne(p => p.Teacher)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TeacherId);
            });
```